# How to set the base URI for the grunt server

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, node.js-connect

I've used a yeoman webapp generator to build my app.

During the development, I simply used `grunt serve` to preview the app.

Now that I'm ready to deploy my app, I've found out that the production environment has a different root context than the development one. In other words, instead of:

```
http://base:port/
```

I'm forced to use

```
http://base:port/subdir_name/
```

This, of course, breaks some stuff.

Is there any way to configure the `connect` server that grunt uses, to take this new root context as it's base URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've found a solution already, but I managed to work around this by using [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) capability of rewriting it's redirects. This is what my config looks like:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 8001,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  proxies: [
    {
        context: '/subdir_name/',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8001,
        https: false,
        xforward: false,
        rewrite: {
          '^/subdir_name': ''
        },
        headers: {
            'x-forwarded-server': 'Grunt Localhost development'
        }
    }
  ],
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect, options) {
        if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
            options.base = [options.base];
        }

        // Setup the proxy
        var middlewares = [];

        middlewares.push(connect.static('.tmp'));
        middlewares.push(connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ));
        middlewares.push(connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ));
        middlewares.push(connect.static(appConfig.app));
        middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest);
        // Serve static files.
        options.base.forEach(function(base) {
            middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
        });

        // Make directory browse-able.
        var directory = options.directory || options.base[options.base.length - 1];
        middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));
        return middlewares;
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Seems interesting. I went the brute-force route of converting all the absolute paths in my app into relative ones. In retrospective, this is how I should have done it in the first place. Still, it's nice to know that this is actually possible. Thank you :)